# AppStore connect API 401 ERROR, while using Firebase\JWT

Tags: php, jwt, app-store-connect, guzzle

I am trying to get reports and data from AppleStore connect API, but it keeps giving me 401 ERROR.

> { "errors": [{ "status": "401", "code": "NOT_AUTHORIZED", "title":
> "Authentication credentials are missing or invalid.", "detail":
> "Provide a properly configured and signed bearer token, and make sure
> that it has not expired. Learn more about Generating Tokens for API
> Requests https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=api-generating-tokens" }]
> }

I was using the guidelines from here => [generating_tokens_for_api_requests](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/generating_tokens_for_api_requests) and using `firebase/php-jwt` library to create jwt token for the Auth. In the App store connect, the key has `Developer` access privileges.

My sample code for it as follows:

```
date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Madrid");
use \Firebase\JWT\JWT;

$appleCon = [
    'privateKey' => "" . file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/AuthKey_XXXXXXXXX.p8'),
    'apiKeyID' => 'XXXXXXXXX',
    'issuerID' => 'XXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXX'
];

$payload = array(
    "iss" => $appleCon['issuerID'],
    "exp" => time() + 1200,
    "aud" => "appstoreconnect-v1",
);

$jwt = JWT::encode($payload, $appleCon['privateKey'], "ES256", $appleCon['apiKeyID']);

$client = new GuzzleHttp\Client(['base_uri' => 'https://api.appstoreconnect.apple.com/v1/']);
$request = new \GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request('GET', 'apps', [
    'headers' => [
        'Authorization' => "Bearer ".$jwt
    ]
]);

$promise = $client->sendAsync($request)->then(function ($response) {
    echo 'I completed! ' . $response->getBody();
});

try {
    $promise->wait();
}
catch (GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException $e) {
    $response = $e->getResponse();
    $responseBodyAsString = $response->getBody()->getContents();

    echo $responseBodyAsString;
}
```

Content of the `AuthKey_XXXXXXXXX.p8` file as follows:

```
-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
-----END PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I am struggling with this issue for two days, if anyone can fix or give some hints to fix this issue, will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a problem with `guzzle`. when I used it without async. it started to work

```
$response = $client->request('GET', 'apps', ['headers' => ['Authorization' => "Bearer $jwt"]])->getBody()->getContents();
```

If anyone can provide me a reason, why it happens when I use it asynchrony, would be interesting to learn it.